# Loading Spring beans from library without importing configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, plugins

I have a Spring Boot application. I have several customers who each have a version of this application, with a few custom `@Component`, `@Service`, etc, classes. I am trying to abstract those custom Spring beans out into library jars which I can place on the classpath and load dynamically.

For example, suppose I have an interface in my core library:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String doSomething();
}
```

I have a different implementations of `MyInterface` in my customer-specific libraries, all annotated with `@Component`.

I want to be able to put

```
@Autowired
List<MyInterface> components;
```

in my main application.

Then, I want to just place my main application in a folder with the appropriate customer's library (or multiple) and run it with

```
java -cp . -jar my-application.jar
```

and have that `@Autowired` pick up the customer's specific components.

Is this possible? I don't want to use `@Import` in the main application, because that requires knowing which customer's library is being loaded.

Comment: Unless I just make sure the `@Configuration` class in each library is named the same and always `@Import` that class name? How would that work if I have two or more of these libraries in the classpath in that case?

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* Yes, but not using `-cp` and `-jar` together, since `-jar` makes it ignore `-cp`. --- [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure this out. Here is a demo project for loading `@Component` objects from plugins at runtime.

https://github.com/imnotpete/plugin-demo

It uses the `loader.properties` file to specify a folder to add to the classpath, and then `@ComponentScan` can include any jars from that folder when autowiring.

loader.properties:

```
loader.path=plugins
```